# How can I make http request into startup class to call http get action in same asp.net web api project?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I need to create http request into startup class to call http get action in same asp.net web api project .

Comment: Do you have anything you have tried already? also what is the purpose of this? what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

> I need to create http request into startup class to call http get action in same asp.net web api project

You can try to inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` into Configure() method , then write the callback for `ApplicationStarted` that would be triggered when the application host has fully started, and make http request within callback method, like below.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime)
{
    //code logic here

    IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetService(typeof(IHttpClientFactory)) as IHttpClientFactory;

    lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnApplicationStartedAsync(_clientFactory).Wait);

    //...
}

private async Task<Action> OnApplicationStartedAsync(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
{
    var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        "https://localhost:44377/api/values");

    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Calling `AddHttpClient` to register `IHttpClientFactory`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient();

    // ...
}
```

Test Result

[image]